# using division in awk script

Tags: awk

I have a file describing allele frequencies and I am trying to use awk to print lines if either one of the frequencies in the two last columns are equal or greater than 0.01. Below is the format of the frequency file: I am interested in the last two frequencies.

```
2L      10000133        A      125/125 115/131 0/125   16/131
2L      10000374        A      121/124 143/143 3/124   0/143
```

From my limited knowledge of awk, I wrote the following code.

```
cat myfile.txt |
awk ' BEGIN { {FS="/"}{OFS="\t"}
     if( ($8>0) && ($8/$9 >= "0.01") || ($10>0) && ($10/$11 >= "0.01"))
             { print $1,$2 }
            }' > myfilteredfile.txt
```

However, the output file myfilteredfile.txt is empty. I expected that the output file would have printed:

```
2L      10000133
2L      10000374
```

...Because both lines contain a frequency in the last two columns that is equal or greater than 0.01. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$  awk '{ split($(NF-1),a,/\//) } { split($NF,b,/\//) } a[1]/a[2] > 0.01 || b[1]/b[2] > 0.01 { print $1, $2 }' file.in
2L 10000133
2L 10000374
```

This splits the last two fields individually on the `/` character and stores the parts in the two arrays `a` and `b`. If either division, when carried out, results in a number greater than 0.01, the two first fields are outputted.

`$NF` is the value of the last field (column) in the input record (line). and `$(NF-1)` is the second to last field's value.

---

The issue with your code is that you're doing everything in a `BEGIN` block.  This block is mainly for initialization and will be executed *before* any data has actually been read. There is also an issue with the chosen value of `FS` that the other answers points out.

You also do not need to quote numbers when they are used as numbers.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues with your existing script.

The first is the separator: you want to split on runs of spaces, and slash; so you need to specify a regular expression which matches that, and use that as `FS`: `FS="[ /]+"`.

The second is that all your code is in the `BEGIN` block. You need to initialise the separators in the `BEGIN` block (or elsewhere, *e.g.* using specific AWK parameters), then use a matcher block to process the lines.

This version works:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="[ /]+"; OFS="\t" }
     (($8>0) && ($8/$9 >= "0.01") || ($10>0) && ($10/$11 >= "0.01")) {
         print $1, $2
     }' myfile.txt
```

Strictly speaking it would be better to use `0.01` instead of `"0.01"` since you’re matching numeric values:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="[ /]+"; OFS="\t" }
     (($8>0) && ($8/$9 >= 0.01) || ($10>0) && ($10/$11 >= 0.01)) {
         print $1, $2
     }' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In `awk`'s `BEGIN{...}` parts is running before reading input line from input, so in your code actually `awk` not reading any input, that's why it's returning nothing. if you want to feed it you need to use `getline` but it will read only one line, you can use `for` loop to read all.

another problem is when you use `FS="/"` it splitting the lines into the fields which delimited by `/`, but the problem is `$8` doesn't exit since max fields are only 5 and those the filed is like this `125 115`, `131 0`, `125 16`, etc.

You can use this code instead to achieve what you want. also note that `awk` can read from file directly not required using `cat` there

```
awk -F'[/ ]+' 'BEGIN{ OFS="\t"}
    {if( ($8>0) && ($8/$9 >= 0.01) || ($10>0) && ($10/$11 >= 0.01))
    { print $1,$2 }
}'  infile
```